# Iterative method for $p$-Laplacian

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, na.numerical-analysis, elliptic-pde, numerical-analysis-of-pde, p-laplace

Consider the following iterative procedure for solving the $p$-Laplace equation $\nabla \cdot (|\nabla u|^{p-2} \nabla u) = 0$ with fixed Dirichlet boundary data:

1. $u_0$ is our initial guess, for example a harmonic function.
2. $u_k$ solves the equation $\nabla \cdot (|\nabla u_{k-1}|^{p-2} \nabla u_k) = 0$.

One would hope that, at least under some conditions, $u_k$ would converge to the $p$-harmonic function with the correct boundary values.

If convenient, we may assume $p > 2$ or other similar condition. $p=2$ is trivial.

This type of iteration has certainly been used to solve other nonlinear equations, so it would be a surprise if nobody had thought to use it for the $p$-Laplace equation. My questions:

1. Does this type of iterative scheme have a name or associated keywords?
2. Are convergence results for this iteration and $p$-Laplace equation known? I am interested in the both the type of convergence and rate of convergence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this method under the name *lagged diffusivity*. I learned it from the paper

> Vogel, Curtis R., and Mary E. Oman. "Iterative methods for total variation denoising." SIAM Journal on Scientific Computing 17.1 (1996): 227-238.

and the paper

> Chan, Tony F., and Pep Mulet. "On the convergence of the lagged diffusivity fixed point method in total variation image restoration." SIAM Journal on Numerical Analysis 36.2 (1999): 354-367.

analyzes the case $p=1$ (with additional regularization). There they write that "This idea is quite commonly used in other PDE applications,
e.g., CFD, and our theory may have applications there as well. " but I don't know more about the background.

There are some newer paper which you find under the same buzzword, but I do not know of any papers that treat other $p$-Laplacians than $p=1$.

Answer (score 0):

A relaxed version of this algorithm for an inhomogenous problem with $1 < p \leq 2$ is investigated by Diening, Fornasier and Wank: https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.03844

The name of the method is "Kačanov Iteration".